# Update IIS Express port in Visual Studio 2012 when creating project template

Tags: visual-studio

I know the title seems a bit misleading but the problem is fairly simple.

I just created a new WebApplication project in Visual Studio 2012 Express for Web, added a couple of extra files and exported the project as a new template. Everything seemed to be working fine until I started debugging a new project instance from this template. When I opened the properties window for the project instance I noticed that the "Project URL" setting under "Web" pointed to `http://localhost:50637` where the port number is the same as the project I used to create the template from. Obviously I want the new project instance to have its own port and I can easily just assign a new one. But my question is whether it is possible for Visual Studio to do automatically when creating new project instances? I imagine I would have to configure the project properties for the template project some how...

Comment: Sorry for the late reply but I haven't had the time to test this yet. Sounds promising though - I'll test it as soon as I get the chance to do so.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After you export the project as a new template, unzip the exported zip file.
This is so that you can edit the .csproj file for the website.
Open up the .csproj file in notepad and edit the following section:

```
<ProjectExtensions>
    <VisualStudio>
      <FlavorProperties GUID="{349c5851-65df-11da-9384-00065b846f21}">
        <WebProjectProperties>
          <UseIIS>True</UseIIS>
          <AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>
          <DevelopmentServerPort>0</DevelopmentServerPort>
          <DevelopmentServerVPath>/</DevelopmentServerVPath>
          ***<IISUrl></IISUrl>***
          <NTLMAuthentication>False</NTLMAuthentication>
          <UseCustomServer>False</UseCustomServer>
          <CustomServerUrl>
          </CustomServerUrl>
          <SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>False</SaveServerSettingsInUserFile>
        </WebProjectProperties>
      </FlavorProperties>
    </VisualStudio>
  </ProjectExtensions>
```

Where the `<IISUrl>http://localhost:59344/</IISUrl>` is, just remove the `http://localhost:59344/` url so that it is blank. 
Then rezip up the folder and install the extension.

A new port number will then be created automatically when the project is created.

Answer (score 1):

In Visual Studio 2019, you need to remove the launchSettings.json from the Properties directory so the visual studio can create the file automatically during the project creation.

Steps:

1- Create a web project

2- Delete the launchSettings.json from the Properties directory.

3- In the Visual Studio 2019, click on the project tab, then click on the export template

Now you can create a new web project by finding your project template, and the VS will automatically create the launchSettings.json file with a random web port.

Comment: Genius. I never would have guessed this. This is most useful in creating low-setup project templates!