# How can I generate a random port number in a Visual Studio custom template

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-templates

I am trying to create a Visual Studio template, based on a default (ASP.NET) web template. However, the default web template is capable of generating an address like http://localhost:5XXXX/ where the XXXX is some randomly generated number, but I am not able to capture that behavior: exporting the (custom) template hard-codes the number.

I would expect that this is done by a template parameter, but there does not seem to be a [predefined](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eehb4faa(v=vs.100).aspx) number generator as template parameter. My next best guess would be some sort of [custom parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0c672h41(v=vs.100).aspx), but those seem pretty static to me.

Any ideas?

Comment: have you seen this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730785/update-iis-express-port-in-visual-studio-2012-when-creating-project-template

Comment: @ManosPasgiannis thanks! Indeed, `<AutoAssignPort>True</AutoAssignPort>` should do the trick

Answer (score 0):

You could change the port number manually as per [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178109.aspx), If I'm not wrong Visual Studio creates the port number on the fly while creating the project.