# Visual Studio custom project template - applicationUrl port number

Tags: .net-core, visual-studio-2017, project-template

Is there any way to add an available random port number for the applicationUrl for a project created from a custom VisualStudio template?
I have created a VS project template for .NET Core projects and have added some placeholder parameters such as "$guid1$" and "$safeprojectname$", but can not find any way to replace the port number for IISExpress application url.

[Default port number is as](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AdeYQ.jpg)

Thanks for any tips and answers!

Answer (score 1):

While not complete, this page gives some help (uses the `dotnet` CLI templating system, not the old templating system):

https://github.com/sayedihashimi/template-sample#generating-ports-for-web-projects

It says:

> If your template consists of a web project, it's likely that you'll want to generate new port numbers to be used when the template is used. This is a bit complex to do correctly, but we will explain the different parts. When defining the support, for each different port number we want the following to create a command line parameter that can be used to explicitly set the port number. If the port number is not passed in by the user, then we want to generate a port number automatically.
>
> To achieve this, we will need to create three new symbols in the template.json file. We will create the following symbols.
>
> - Parameter that the user can pass in
> - A generated port number
> - Symbol to coalesce the user parameter and the generated port
>   Here is a sample, where we specify the range that we want the port number to be in.

```
"HttpsPort": {
  "type": "parameter",
  "datatype": "integer",
  "description": "Port number to use for the HTTPS endpoint in launchSettings.json."
},
"HttpsPortGenerated": {
  "type": "generated",
  "generator": "port",
  "parameters": {
  "low": 44300,
  "high": 44399
  }
},
"HttpsPortReplacer": {
  "type": "generated",
  "generator": "coalesce",
  "parameters": {
  "sourceVariableName": "HttpsPort",
  "fallbackVariableName": "HttpsPortGenerated"
  },
  "replaces": "44345"
}
```

> **HttpsPort** is the user facing parameter that can be passed in when calling dotnet new.
>
> **HttpsPortGenerated** is the generated port number. In this example we specified a low and a high value. The generated port number will be between those. These parameters are optional.
>
> **HttpsPortReplacer** is the symbol that will decide between HttpsPort and HttpsPortGenerated. If a value is provided via the command line (HttpsPort) it will be given preference. Take note of 44345 in this symbol. This is the port number that the source files use. Where ever this string is found in the template content, it will be replaced with the new port number.
>
> For a full example of sourceName see src/Content/MyWebApp/.template.config/template.json

Answer (score 0):

For IIS Express you have the AutoAssignPort property that you might use.

Its from a previous SO question here: [Update IIS Express port in Visual Studio 2012 when creating project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15730785/update-iis-express-port-in-visual-studio-2012-when-creating-project-template)

Comment: It did unfortunately not work since the VS templates for .NET core projects are a bit different. Tried to add <IISUrl></IISUrl> under  <PropertyGroup> but it still did not work.

Answer (score 0):

For .NET Core projects, remove the `launchSettings.json` file from the `Properties` folder before using `Project\Export Template` to create the Template. Visual Studio will automatically generate the `launchSettings.json` file.

**If you are creating the project manually:**
just remove it from the `Properties` folder and also remove the file reference in the `MyTemplate.vstemplate` file.
Leave the empty folder node:

```
<Folder Name="Properties" TargetFolderName="Properties">
        
</Folder>
```

This works for both Visual Studio 2019 and Visul Studio 2022.

I did not try it with Visual Studio 2017.